# Getting null argument while routing through firebase push notifications flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, navigation

I am trying to route to a certain screen with some argument when clicked on push notifications. So far it is working fine when app is in foreground or in background but open. But when the app is terminated it is routing to the correct screen but there is some issue with the argument, it is null.

```
const payload = admin.messaging.MessagingPayload = {
  data : {
    'type' : 'msg',
    'route' : 'chat-screen',
    'argument' : sentby,
  },
  notification : {
    title : senderData.user_name,
    body: original.message,  
    image: notificationIcon,
    android_channel_id : "Finiso",
    channel_id : "Finiso",
    clickAction : 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
  }
}
```

This is the code for the notification which I am triggering through cloud functions.

```
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification.title);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
```

added this in main.dart

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) async {
  if (message != null) {
    print(message.data);
    routeNotification(message);
  }
});
```

listening to messages and on app open trigger.

```
void routeNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
final routeName = message.data['route'];
if (routeName == ActivityFeed.routeName) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ActivityFeed.routeName);
} else {
  if (message.data['type'] == 'msg') {
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      message.data['route'],
      arguments: message.data['argument'],
    );
  }
}
}
```

This is the routing function I used above

[Image showing console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEYgC.png)

It is printing the first two lines from main.dart and "null" is the argument I am trying to get.

Can anyone help me on this. I have no idea what's going on.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you observing this on both Android and iOS?

Comment: On Android haven't tested on iOS yet.

Comment: Have you tried to listen to `onMessageOpenedApp` as well? I am not sure but maybe this works when app is terminated on Android and opened after user clicks on a notification, and `getInitialMessage` will be available on iOS.

Comment: Already using it for background notifications. onMessageOpenedApp returns a stream if app has opened from a background state (not terminated).

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer but I'm not positive on the reason **why** this is happening yet. Let's collaborate on this.

First of all, I think the routing is happening automatically for you. In all other scenarios except the terminal state, you are pushing the route and handling adding the arguments. In the terminal state, the app is ignoring your `initialRoute` and using the route from your push notification.

Usually when you setup `MaterialApp` your initialRoute is used:

```
MaterialRoute(
  initialRoute: '/whatever_you_put_here'
...
)
```

It seems that `WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.defaultRouteName` ([source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/app.dart#L1331)) is being set within the flutter code and this is causing your default route to be this route instead of whatever you are passing to `MaterialApp`.

Reading the [flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PlatformDispatcher/defaultRouteName.html), it looks like this property is only set when someone calls `FlutterView.setInitialRoute` from Android.

That is the answer to your question.

--

I don't know what is calling `FlutterView.setInitialRoute`. A [search of FlutterFire code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Afirebase%2Fflutterfire%20FlutterView&type=code) seems to show no instances.